# oVirt requirements and other web based mgmt tools for kvm

Tags: virtualization, web, linux-kvm, requirements

I'm evaluating different virtualization management tools for KVM virtualization. I've a kvm ready server with 32GB ram. I'm looking for web based management tools where different people can manage/create/clone and so forth their virtual machines.

I've already tested [Archipel](http://archipelproject.org/) and [WebVirtMgr](https://www.webvirtmgr.net/). In my opinion Archipel is still too buggy and WebVirtMgr is too simple.

[oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) is my next choice but I'm a little bit concerned because I want to run the manager and kvm on the same server. The requirements for oVirt are pretty high: min. 4 GB of ram, better 16 GB.

My server has only 32 GB ram so I'm concerned that the manager takes too much of the avaiable RAM.

Has somebody experience with oVirt and can assume that it takes so much ram or does somebody have another web based management tool recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say for a single host, oVirt might be on the heavy side, but the oVirt all in one distribution makes it **really** easy to get started with that. The RAM requirements include running VMs - the oVirt manager itself is a JBoss application, which is rather memory thirsty, but 32GB of RAM will be plenty for running a few VMs on a single host with oVirt.

Cheers,
Dave.

Comment: Thanks for your information. What do you exactly mean by "the ram requirements include running vms"? Do you have some details about how much ram oVirt takes at its own?

Comment: Each VM will have its own RAM requirements (you might want to allocate 8GB of RAM to a VM, depending on the workload). oVirt does some tricks related to reusing identical read-only memory pages across multiple VMs, so 3 VMs using 8GB each will not take 24GB, usually, but that is approximately the case. Add in 2GB or more for the oVirt manager, plus whatever your host operating system needs.

Answer (score 0):

for a single host use case, 2-4GB of RAM should be fine. there is also an all-in-one deployment mode for this use case

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I am not saying your answer is invalid, but do you have "proof" you can write here regarding your statement? it could be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen that there is a all-in-one deployment mode as well. Still I'm concerned about the 2-4GB ram consumption regarding to the 32GB memory of the server. You said that 2-4GB of ram should be fine. Have you measured it with top or something similar?